# What are those asyncio files in /proc/*/fd

Tags: python, linux, python-asyncio

Running an `asyncio.sleep` task causes the following files to be present in `/proc/*/fd`:

```
lrwx------ 1 mango mango 64 27. Dez 12:40 3 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 mango mango 64 27. Dez 12:40 4 -> 'socket:[330143]'
lrwx------ 1 mango mango 64 27. Dez 12:40 5 -> 'socket:[330144]'
```

What does this stuff do for asyncio?

I had a problem with multiprocessing that was solved by creating a new event loop in the new process, so I assume there is some link between the processes. Either a pipe (which I think is also a file?) or this stuff.

Comment: See [man proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for general information. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463548/what-is-anon-inode-in-the-output-of-ls-l-proc-pid-fd) may also help.

Comment: Note that a Stack Overflow question should be about _a specific problem that you actually face_. If you don't have a bug caused by this, you don't have any problem at all, much less a specific one. The whole point of abstractions is so that, when they aren't [leaking](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/), you don't need to know what's on the other side of the API boundary. Once you have a leak -- where the implementation detail causes a bug -- _then_ there's an on-topic question.

Comment: See also [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918)

Comment: Thanks. I have added some background on why I'm asking this question. It's based on an assumption though, and I only vaguely understood how to reproduce it in my application.

Comment: Ahh! Forking off children does indeed make things more interesting (in ways that can well cause bugs). There's a close-on-fork flag available at the operating system level, but I have no idea offhand if asyncio uses it.

Answer (score 1):

> What does this stuff do for asyncio?

Those are resources acquired by the asyncio event loop for its internal workings.

The first file descriptor is likely to be the file descriptor returned by [`epoll_create()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_create.2.html), which is passed to [`epoll()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) in order to used to monitor network and other IO in order to resume coroutines suspended while waiting for IO.

The second and third file descriptor are likely to refer to the socket pair created by the event loop in order to "wake up" when a [signal is received](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#unix-signals) or when another thread [requests execution of a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe) in the event loop thread. In [both](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bf64d9064ab641b1ef9a0c4bda097ebf1204faf4/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L796) [cases](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bf64d9064ab641b1ef9a0c4bda097ebf1204faf4/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1799) the wakeup is implemented by [writing a byte](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bf64d9064ab641b1ef9a0c4bda097ebf1204faf4/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py#L129) to the write end of the socket pair, which notifies the event loop's reactor that monitors the read end.